# How do I make a password from one `input` match another as I type?

Tags: angularjs, django, input

I have this at the top of my HTML file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app=    angular.module("app",[]);
    app.config(function($interpolateProvider){
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol("[[[");
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol("]]]");
    });

    app.controller("MainCtrl",function($scope){
        $scope.name=    "World";
    })
</script>
```

I have two `input` elements.

`<input id="id_password1" name="password1" ng-model="pw" placeholder="Password" type="password" required="">`

and

`<input id="id_password2" name="password2" ng-model="pw" placeholder="Confirm password" type="password" required="">`

As I type my password into the first input, I'd like to fill the second with what I'm typing in the first. How do I do this?

**Edit**: These `input`s are in a `form` made with Django.

In my `forms.py`, I have this.

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    '''
    Form that makes user using just email as username
    '''
    username=   forms.EmailField(label=_("Email"), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Email", "id":"id_register_username"}))
    password1=  forms.CharField(label=_("Password"), widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Password", "ng-model":"pw"}))
    password2=  forms.CharField(label=_("Password confirmation"), widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Confirm password", "ng-model":"pw"}))
```

Comment: they should be already, since they both have the same `ng-model` value, unless there is a problem with their `$scope`.  You haven't provided enough code here to really understand what the problem is.

Comment: Updated @Claies

Comment: I created a generic plunker, dropped your two inputs in a form, and I don't see what your problem is:  http://plnkr.co/edit/Vww8K7QEEPuXGDLiwdaD?p=preview.  However, the script you pasted wouldn't even run without throwing errors, since that's not how you declare a controller in any version of angular past 1.2, which is 4 years old.  It certainly wouldn't work with the 1.5.6 version you are showing here.

Comment: Updated my code and also added the fact that I'm using Django. Maybe that is affecting it

Comment: I doubt Django would be affecting it, but none of the code you posted is a [mcve].  More of the HTML is necessary to diagnose the problem here, since you aren't really showing what controller the form is in (or if it is in a controller at all).

Comment: What's the point of this? The reason to have two password fields is to get the user to manually type it twice to make sure they have it right. Filling the second one in automatically bypasses the reason for having it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

What you want will work by `ng-model` with same name, but it's not confirm password!

However, i add 2 sample for your question:

---

**sample 1: 2 same ng-model**

```js
var app = angular.module("app", [])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
<input name="password1" ng-model="password" type="password">

<input name="password2" ng-model="password" type="password">
</div>
```

---

**sample 2: 2 different ng-model**

```js
var app = angular.module("app", [])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
<input name="password1" ng-model="password" type="password" ng-change="confirmPassword = password">
password is: {{password}}
<input name="password2" ng-model="confirmPassword" type="password">
confirmPassword is: {{confirmPassword}}

</div>
```

> Fill free to ask question.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var mirrorInput = function() {
  var input1 = document.getElementById("id_password1");
  var input2 = document.getElementById("id_password2");
  input1.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    input2.value = input1.value;
  })
};

window.onload = function() {
  mirrorInput();
};
```

```html
<input id="id_password1" name="password1" ng-model="pw" placeholder="Password" type="password" required="">

<input id="id_password2" name="password2" ng-model="pw" placeholder="Confirm password" type="password" required="">
```

Comment: This works, but is **definitely not the angularjs way to handle the problem**.

Comment: please add more details to your answer